# LeetCode output is different from IDE | Remove duplicates of sorted list

Tags: python, arrays, list, duplicates

I'm a python beginner. I tried the [classic question](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/) on removing duplicates from sorted list. I'm confused that my code works on my IDE and produces the correct output given the test cases [1,1,2] and [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]. It shows k=2 and 5 and resulting nums = [1,2] and [0,1,2,3,4] respectively. However, when I ran it in LeetCode, it shows the resulting list has no change, which remains the same as the input list. Why is it like that?

Here is my code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        k = 0
        i = 0
        while i < len(nums):
            temp = nums[i+1:]
            while nums[i] in temp:
                temp.remove(nums[i])
            nums = nums[:i+1] + temp
            k += 1
            i += 1
        return k
```

I know this is not the optimal code, and I understand the posted solutions, which are more efficient. I just don't understand why my code fails. I'm new to LeetCode and has encountered another instance like this, where my code produces the correct output on my IDE, but LeetCode shows a different output. Is there any nuance I should notice when writing code on LeetCode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just read [the task in LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/) thoroughly and implement what is required. There are at least 2 major and obvious mistakes in the given code.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The hyperlink in your comment refers to a different Leetcode challenge

Comment: Note that `nums` is not being returned by the function - the only way that LeetCode can check if you did the right thing is by examining the list that was passed to your function, to see if you modified it correctly.  But you're not modifying it, you're assigning a brand-new value to `nums`, which breaks any connection with the original list that LeetCode is checking.  You have to perform the modifications in-place.

Comment: @DarkKnight. how do you know? OP didn't provide a link and the title of the challenge I found is 80+% similar.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The hyperlink you provided refers to a challenge based on singly linked lists. Also, a simple search on Leetcode reveals the actual problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community: please use `[edit]` to generate an [edit] link. Bots should actually be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, it's a very bad idea to modify an iterable whilst enumerating it. Your code may work for some values but not all.

Try this:

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        i = 0
        for e in nums[1:]:
            if e != nums[i]:
                i += 1
                nums[i] = e
        return i + 1
```